# Windows won’t boot first time but does second time

Tags: hard-drive, boot, sleep

I have a problem with my work laptop that it a little hard to describe in one sentence.

After having new ram added as well as a second nvme drive, my laptop now never boots when I first turn it on. It goes to bitlocker, I enter my password and then it hangs on the dell/windows boot screen.

If I hard turn off and repeat the process it will work immediately. It does this every time.

As a side effect the machine will now never sleep properly, if I put the machine to sleep I will be back to the same boot loop issue and my machine state is lost.

Both drives in the machine are protected with boot locker and different passwords

Comment: First step, as always, update the firmware (UEFI).

Comment: Work laptop? You need to ask your IT folks.

Comment: @ChanganAuto updating firmware didn't work.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1703792/windows-won-t-boot-first-time-but-does-second-time?noredirect=1#comment2627508_1703792